# Alternative to Dark Energy

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, space-expansion, hawking-radiation, cosmological-constant

If Black Holes consume mass and re radiate it in the form of massless photons the mass of the universe is declining.  Could this explain the accelerating expansion of the universe without the necessity of invoking Dark Energy?

Comment: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope estimation?

Comment: The universe does not accelerate, so your question is moot. Here is just one of many studies debunking the acceleration idea: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep35596 - and here is an overview of a German theoretical physicist with more links: http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2019/11/dark-energy-might-not-exist-after-all.html

Answer (score 5):

No, you can’t explain accelerating expansion in this way. There are three separate problems with your proposed explanation.

First of all, mass isn’t relevant. In General Relativity, gravity and the expansion of the universe depends on *energy* (and momentum), not on mass. The massless photons carry away energy, and the energy of the hole decreases by the same amount, so energy is conserved. (Momentum is also conserved.)

Second, the energy and momentum of photons does gravitate in a different way than the energy and momentum of black holes. But both cause a *deceleration* of the expansion, not an acceleration.

Third, all black holes that we know of are not radiating any net photons, because their Hawking temperature is far lower than the temperature of the cosmic microwave background. They are all *absorbing* photons.

Comment: If it depends on energy, then it does also depend on mass, doesn't it?

Comment: For particles with mass, yes. For massless particles, no.

Comment: Oh, you're only referring to massless particles. Then I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Most black holes are still consuming far more ambient light than they are radiating through Hawking radiation. More fundamentally, energy has the same effect on the curvature of spacetime whether it is light energy or mass energy, and black holes do not change the total amount. So no, the acceleration of Universal expansion must be explained some other way.

Comment: Yes, energy has the same effect whether it is light energy or mass energy. But pressure (momentum flux) also matters and they don’t have the same pressure. This is why matter-dominated and radiation- dominated universes expand differently.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. Make sure you understand what [dark energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy#Technical_definition) is.

> In standard cosmology, there are three components of the universe: matter, radiation, and dark energy. Matter is anything whose energy density scales with the inverse cube of the scale factor, i.e., $\rho \propto a^{-3}$, while radiation is anything which scales to the inverse fourth power of the scale factor ($\rho \propto a^{-4}$). This can be understood intuitively: for an ordinary particle in a cube-shaped box, doubling the length of an edge of the box decreases the density (and hence energy density) by a factor of eight ($2^3$). For radiation, the decrease in energy density is greater, because an increase in spatial distance also causes a redshift.
>
> The final component, dark energy, is an intrinsic property of space, and so has a constant energy density regardless of the volume under consideration ($\rho \propto a^0$). Thus, unlike ordinary matter, it does not get diluted with the expansion of space.

Photons are radiation - their energy density scales to the inverse fourth power of the scale factor. Dark energy is fundamentally different from photons, and cannot be made up of it.